# Containing WPF-web-based app and WPF-desktop app in same csproj.

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application, which until now - was an browser-based application. Now - due some changes in project i want to be able to run that application as desktop application. My question is - is it possible, that by using single CSProj file, and adding extra build configuration, to have single WPF Project which would build to desktop and web-based app? I want to be able to choose between options:

- Debug (application is building as web-WPF-app, and is launched in web browser)
- Release (same)
- Debug Desktop (application is building as desktop-WPF-app, and is launched as client-desktop app)
- Release Desktop (same)

Kind regards

Szymon D.

Answer (score 1):

The output type of a project is independent from the Build configuration in Visual Studio.

Also, why? Why not factor out the things that are shared into DLLs and creating separate projects per output type?

Comment: Good answer.  Even as a WPF it is hard to fool it into using more than 1 starting window.